# How to anchor rotated TextBlock to the top?

Tags: wpf, xaml

With the following code the text ABCDE starts from the top of the grid and places the letters outside the grid.

How can I make it so the text stays inside the grid and the last letter ends at the top of the grid?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="ABCDE"  >
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What happens if you use a `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LayoutTransform` instead of a `RenderTransform`

`LayoutTransform` is applied during the layout pass, not the render pass

```
<TextBlock Text="ABCDE"  >
    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
</TextBlock>
```